# Properties in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why properties are undefined after {} how to fix it?

```
function GitMetrics() {
  var arr = ["qwer", "asdf"];
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    this[item] = 1;
    var e = this.qwer; //1
  });
  var t = this.qwer; //undefined
}
exports.GitMetrics = GitMetrics;
```

Comment: because the `this` points to different object each time.

Comment: e.g, use fat arrow syntax for the callback.

Comment: Fully understanding - to the point of not having to think about it anymore the context of "this" is one of the things that hurts most about Javascript.
I recommend reading https://toddmotto.com/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/ for some clarity. @Sirko has the easy way out - don't declare a "real" function, but use the =>() syntax to keep the context of "this" to what you'd intended, rather than function scope, which is what you've got going now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1 Using fat arrow (ES6 required).

```
arr.forEach((item) => {
  this[item] = 1;
  var e = this.qwer; //1
});
```

2 Passing `this` as argument.

```
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  this[item] = 1;
  var e = this.qwer; //1
}, this);
```

Answer (score -2):

I save reference on this in variable tmp.

```
function GitMetrics() {
   var arr = ["qwer", "asdf"];
   var tmp = this;
   arr.forEach(function(item) {
      tmp[item] = 1;
      var e = tmp.qwer; //1
   });
   var t = this.qwer; //1 it works
   }
exports.GitMetrics = GitMetrics;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are unacceptable--please provide an explanation. Also, please properly format code.